# Can i know if an image is transparent at a specific position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-10

I'm making a game in javascript (for IE 10) that has a colision system.
I want to colide the objects only when 2 visible parts colide, i want to ignore the transparent parts of the images.

Has any way to know if a position from an < img > is transparent or not?

Comment: hey man is your objects in circle?

Comment: No.. Its a Balloon... Not so easy :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Burn' the image into an HTML5 canvas, then get the specific pixel from the canvas and check its Alpha (http://falcon80.com/HTMLCanvas/PixelManipulation/getImageData.html).

I think it would be easier if you only worked with HTML5 canvas instead of moving around DOM segments.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following post :

You can use an image with the old-fashioned < map > and < area > tags.

[Hover only on non-transparent part of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689308/hover-only-on-non-transparent-part-of-image)